# How to enable SSH remote server on "Windows 10" that works with X11 forwarding ? I get "Remote: No xauth program; cannot forward X11."

Tags: windows, ssh, x11-forwarding, x-windows

I've seen a ton of posts on this topic, but I haven't found a post that covers my specific use case.

I want to connect to my Windows 10 PC via ssh and see X graphical apps on my mac laptop. The reason for this is that I'm developing remotely on vscode on my mac, but I'm using the GPUs from this Windows 10 server that is also being used with its GUI for some other tasks.

I'm able to see the x11-apps from my mac (tested with xclock, for example) when I connect to another Linux servers, so the config on the local client side (my mac laptop) seems to be OK.

from the output of debug1 after ssh with -v flag when connecting from Mac client to Windows ssh server:

```
debug1: Remote: No xauth program; cannot forward X11.
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
```

(for reference: X11 forwarding is enabled on the sshd_config file on Windows.)

So it seems that an xauth program is missing. I know that we can install xauth on Linux, but how do we do this on Windows? On some posts I've read that using Xming, but this is to use Windows as a client, not as the server.

I've noticed that there are many post pointing to using things like WSL to make X11 forwarding work; but none of them cover my use case. What am I missing? Is it not possible to do this on Windows? Do I have to do it from WSL to connect to the Windows PC?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it right you're running an X server on your Mac and you want to run the applications (X clients) on the Windows box (to use the bigger CPU horsepower there I presume) with the display redirected back to the X server on the Mac.

You may be confused by my use of "Client" and "Server".
In X-Windows terminology the side where the displaying is done is the SERVER and the system where the application is running is the CLIENT.
This is exactly the opposite of what most people would consider client/server and is a major source of confusion whenever X-Windows is being discussed.

Windows doesn't include an X Windows client environment.
You don't just need xauth, there is a lot more to it. You need the whole X client setup.

So this is never going to work.

WSL allows you to run a Linux environment inside Windows. Inside that Linux environment X can be available, but it can be very complicated to make it work as you are stacking multiple layers of complexity on top of Windows.

Or you get a proper X client setup directly in Windows. CygWin or XMing come to mind, both have X Server and X  client, but both are not really native Windows programs, but Linux programs compiled in such a way that they can run inside Windows. Getting that to work can also be a can of worms.

Either way: You still have to compile your X client applications to run under either WSL Linux, Windows/CygWIn of Windows/XMing in order to be able to run them on the Windows server.

With the above in mind you may have to re-think what you are trying to achieve. It is a lot of effort. Is the CPU benefit of the Windows server worth it?

Comment: The terminology makes perfect sense if you consider what the service being performed is, namely drawing on the screen (and dealing with keyboard and mouse I/O). Whenever we talk about client and server, the entity that is *providing* the service is the server and the entity that *uses* the service is the client. So, in the context of X, the *server* is what draws on the screen and the *client* is something like Firefox which asks the server to draw on the screen.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I totally agree. It does make sense from a data-flow logic. But it still confuses the hell out of people. It seems everybody these days thinks of "client" as "my local computer" and "server" as the "remote system". And that is often true, but not always.